# AFNetworking Not Working with Xcode 5.1.1 and Cocoapods - Redefinition Issues

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, afnetworking

I have a project I which I need to use AFNetworking so after downloading the source files, importing them manually and struggling for hours with no luck I figured I'd use Cocoapods as it should surely be easier. Unfortunately not, I'm now getting lots of issues regarding redefinition of Enumerators, Duplicate interface definition and property has a previous declaration.

[image]

If anyone can help me with why I could be getting this and how I can get rid of the error it would be much appreciated. I was under the impression it is meant to be easy using Cocoapods but as of yet I haven't seen that!

Comment: You need to delete the copy of AFNetworking you manually imported, and only use the CocoaPods one.

Comment: CocoaPods installs everything to a separate project in your workspace called "Pods". It looks like you have two copies of every file, one in your "BranchOut" project and once in your "Pods" project.